# Query data in EJS with NodeJS and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I've captured data and display them by doing this:

```
const items = [];

Task.find({},(err,tasks)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        tasks.forEach((task)=>{
            items.push(task.name);
        })
    }
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    today = date.getDate();
    res.render('list', { kindOfDay: today, items: items });
})
```

But when I try to do this instead, it failed to display the data with out any error:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const items = [];

    Task.find({}, (err, tasks) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            tasks.forEach((task) => {
                items.push(task.name);
                //console.log(task.name) still works
            })
        }
    });

    today = date.getDate();
    res.render('list', { kindOfDay: today, items: items });
})
```

Does anybody knows why the code above refuse to display data when I render the 'list' page?
Thank you!

Comment: res.render is executed before items array is populated , as nodejs is asynchronous ,wrap up task.find inside async await function , so that res.render calls after the processing is completed

Comment: Or you can try putting render code inside the scope of Task.find function

Comment: use async await while fetching data from db and you'll be good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoose `find` method is asynchronous, `res.render` might/would execute before the array gets populated. your code should be as below

```
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      const items = [];

      Task.find({}, (err, tasks) => {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              tasks.forEach((task) => {
                  items.push(task.name);
                  //console.log(task.name) still works
              });
          }
          today = date.getDate();
          res.render('list', { kindOfDay: today, items: items });
      });
  })
```